# Codification, write an integer in a file

Tags: c, huffman-code

I am doing a coding task in the C language, I go well until the part of reading the symbol and assign the corresponding code according to a table. I must concatenate several codes until they reach 32 bits in length, to accomplish this I must write them in a file.
This method of writing to file is giving me a lot of problems, I'm trying to do it with the fputc() function.

I can not change the declaration of the function because they request it for the homework.
I create a mask to be able to write the integer by bytes because they also suggest that the teachers of the course.
The program with that code works but when I see the file with a binary viewer it only prints zero.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
void write_int(FILE* fp, unsigned int buffer, int nbytes){
    if ( (nbytes <= sizeof(int)) && (nbytes>=0) ){ 
        unsigned int aux;
        int i;
        for (i=4; i>(4-nbytes) ; i--){
            aux = buffer & new_mask( ((i*8)-1),((i-1)*8)); 
            fputc(aux,fp)
        }
    fputc('\n',fp);
    }else{
        printf("nbytes out of range");
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is `new_mask`?

Comment: Some operating systems support text-file translation. Did you try an fopen with "b" appended to the mode? Also, dumb question, do you do an fclose() before viewing the file?

Comment: new_mask(max,min) creates a number whose binary representation has 1's between max and min and 0's in the other.

Comment: i do fclose() i'm going to probe with b appended

Comment: If the goal is to write the bytes of `buffer` to the file, shouldn't you be doing some shifting in the `aux =` line? Also I'd suggest using `sizeof(unsigned int)` instead of `4`. You might try doing a `printf()` with the `fputc()` to see if the output is as expected on the screen.

Comment: with printf its ok and if i do printf(FILE*,"%u",aux) its ok too but with fputc() don't work

Comment: with a append in fopen() work's!! naow i have to write byte to byte thats not work yet

Comment: sorry about my english i don't write very well

Comment: You're doing better than a large number of people I've interacted with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fputc is used to write one ASCII-character into a file.

`int fputc(int, FILE*)` //this int is converted to unsigned before going to the file(your bits are probably being messed up here)

1- solution: Open this file in binary mode and write using fwrite

```
fp = fopen("filename", "wb+");
fwrite(buffer, 4, 1, fp);
```

*since integers on most computers have 32bits(4bytes) this should write your whole 32 bits at once in a binary file

2- solution: Assuming that you can't open the file in binary mode inside this function... you could simply write 4chars usgin fprintf.

`int fprintf(FILE*, format, ....);`

*note: it's hard to help more than this, because it's not clear what is nature of these symbols. 
ex: binary stream, integer number, ascii, utf, etc